# Per unit quantity meaning

Tags: terminology, definition, dimensional-analysis, units

What does per unit quantity mean? like distance covered per unit time? Or mass per unit volume?

Comment: It is useful to define such a unit sometimes. For example "power per pixel". But you won't get much help if you're not particular about where you encountered such a unit.

Comment: Hi and welcome to PSE. 10 kg per cubic meter, for instance, which is some unit of mass "per" some unit of volume, means that in every cubic meter (in every square, in other words, of volume $V=1m\ \times\ 1m\ \times 1m$) there exists mass equal to $10\ kg$. I do not thing that there is something more to understand other than that. Other examples follow the same line of reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

"per unit x" is a conventional phrase used when we want to define a quantity without being specific about the units used.

For example, speed can be (loosely) defined as "distance covered per unit time". If you measure distance in metres and time in seconds then you get speed in meters per second. If you measure distance in miles and time in hours then you get speed in miles per hour.

In the same way, density can be defined as "mass per unit volume". In SI units, density has units of kilograms per cubic metre. In CGS units density has units of grams per cubic centimetre.